# React Context declared outside of component is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-context, react-hook-form

I'm working with [react-hook-form](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form), which implements a `<Controller />` component that wraps around any `<input />` for controlled fields.

I'm trying to use abstraction, so that I can make any Form component reusable in the future, by way of:

```
const ControlContext = createContext({});

interface AbstractFormProps<T extends DataTypes> {
  alert: {
    title: string;
    message: string;
  };
  dialog: {
    title: string;
    message: string;
    trigger: JSX.Element;
  };
  form: {
    data?: T;
    schema: ZodObject<any>;
    onSubmit: (...args: any[]) => any;
    onError: (...args: any[]) => any;
  };
  children?: JSX.Element;
}

function AbstractForm<T extends DataTypes>(props: AbstractFormProps<T>) {
  const { children, alert, dialog, form } = props;

  const _form = useForm<T>({
    resolver: zodResolver(form.schema),
    defaultValues: form.data as DefaultValues<T>,
  });

  const [control, setControl] = React.useState<Control<T, any>>(_form.control);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setControl(_form.control);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <ControlContext.Provider value={control}>
        <form>
          <AbstractDialog
            trigger={dialog.trigger}
            title={dialog.title}
            description={dialog.message}
          >
            <>
              {children}
              <ConfirmDialog
                title={alert.title}
                message={alert.message}
                onConfirm={_form.handleSubmit(form.onSubmit, form.onError)}
                trigger={<Button>Submit</Button>}
              />
            </>
          </AbstractDialog>
        </form>
      </ControlContext.Provider>
    </>
  );
}
```

To explain: I'm passing any `Fields` I create to `<AbstractForm />` as `{children}`, such that I could dynamically create forms in my app. This is why I created a Context for it. I'm trying to export said context, then set its value as the form's Control whenever it's used. I tried both `useEffect` and `useState`, but no luck.

For reference, this is the code for my field component:

```
function AbstractField<T extends DataTypes[keyof DataTypes]>(
  props: AbstractFieldProps<T>
) {
  const { field, dropdownValues, formSetValue } = props;

  const control = useContext(ControlContext);

  return (
    <Controller
      control={control as Control} // Returns {} if not casted to Control
      name={field.key}
      rules={{ required: true }}
      render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => {
        return (
          <div className="flex flex-col flex-grow basis-0">
            <Label className="my-2" htmlFor={field.key}>
              {field.key.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + field.key.slice(1)}
            </Label>
            {field.valueType === "text" ? (
              <Input
                key={field.key}
                id={field.key}
                type="text"
                onChange={onChange}
                value={value as string}
              />
            ) : null}
            {field.valueType === "number" ? (
              <Input
                key={field.key}
                id={field.key}
                type="number"
                onChange={(event) => {
                  onChange?.(parseInt(event.target.value));
                }}
                value={value as number}
              />
            ) : null}
            {field.valueType === "select" ? (
              <Combo
                name={field.key}
                title={field.key.toLowerCase()}
                defaultValue={value}
                formSetValue={formSetValue}
                elements={dropdownValues}
              />
            ) : null}
          </div>
        );
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

And here I'm creating a new form, by that logic:

```
function UserEditForm({ trigger, user }: { trigger: JSX.Element, user: User }) {
  return (
    <AbstractForm
      alert={{
        title: "Are you sure you wish to update this User?",
        message: "This action is irreversible.",
      }}
      dialog={{
        title: "Edit User",
        message: "Edit an existing user",
        trigger: trigger,
      }}
      form={{
        schema: userSchema,
        onSubmit: UserForm.onSubmit,
        onError: UserForm.onError
      }}
    >
      <AbstractField
        field={UserFormFields.get("_id")!}
      />
    </AbstractForm>
  );
}
```

*Is it possible that it's using the exported value of* `{}` *on compile-time?*

...or am I just not understanding [Context](https://react.dev/reference/react/useContext)?

Comment: If you use [`FormProvider`](https://www.react-hook-form.com/api/formprovider/), you can use [`Controller`](https://www.react-hook-form.com/api/usecontroller/controller/) without having to pass the control. You're attempting to re-invent what react-hook-form already does. Your `AbstractForm` is `useForm` + `FormProvider`.

Comment: @AdamJenkins Thank you! I'm not sure how I didn't see that...

Comment: @AdamJenkins I just switched to FormProvider, but just to be sure: am I using Context correctly, or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: What’s your error message?